# problems when writing a C proxy

Tags: c, http, proxy

I am now writing a simple c version proxy. As am a beginning. I don not know how it works. I've got the header from request.

> GET http://www.google.com/intl/zh-CN/options/ HTTP/1.1 Host:
>   www.google.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X
>   10.7; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: zh-cn,zh;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3 Accept-Encoding:
>   gzip, deflate Proxy-Connection: keep-alive Cookie:
>   __utma=173272373.193679248.1334660049.1334660049.1334660049.1; __utmz=173272373.1334660049.1.1.utmcsr=google.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; PREF=ID=fa48aeea1d8f76b9:U=a085cdf552ee303a:FF=0:TM=1329307863:LM=1334660032:S=rrb7tn0TSlZxymZj; NID=57=eF8kg0Geq6xPrc4flrw-ps5WXffeSS16kpTjTUXb_7-4tw0wXKbXKeWsa2UXr7o2gvV0o4-D9nVO5JV8PBFY5wT25oesLvlg7UiDwNM1wdC90WC3IqoZi3Kk0Pyh7Aj

_

What the next step should I do. Need I modify the header and send it to the web server. I've parser the URL from the header and connected to the WEBSERVER, and I just got another header. How can I get the body of the page?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question.  What library are you using to perform the HTTP request?

Comment: Its better u go through the HTTP RFC. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt. It may help u a lot

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a small amount of source code.

Answer (score 1):

The body is separated from the headers by an empty line (technically, `\r\n\r\n`). Just keep reading what the remote server sends.

Comment: I used socket to access the web server.

Comment: That's great. Are you having problems reading from the socket?